# How to find the intersect point between two sine waves?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the points where (y = 2 sin x) and (x = 2 sin y) intersect, besides (0, 0).
I've managed to work out that 2 sin x should equal x.

My classpad can give me an answer that I believe is right, simply by looking at these two sine functions on a graph.  But how can I go about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the numerical value of the intersection with a common scientific calculator repeatedly calculating "sin" (take care that trigonometric functions are set to "rad") and multiplying the result by $2$ until the result stabilizes (at each iteration you get the same value). You can choose any starting point between $0$ and $\pi$ (but staying close to $1.9$ will make the process shorter). You are in fact looking for the attractor point of the iterated function $y=2\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

plugging $$x=2\sin(y)$$ into your first equation you will get
$$y=2\sin(2\sin(y))$$ this equation can only be solved by a numerical way,e.g. the Newton-Raphson method. one solution is given by $$1.895494267$$